# spark-submit using YARN master programmatically not working

Tags: python, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am using Apache Spark 2.1.0. If I do:

```
$ spark-submit --master yarn main.py
```

The Spark python module will execute on YARN properly and the application will show up on YARN web browser GUI as a finished application.

If I do it programmatically, it doesn't show up in YARN GUI, so I am assuming it doesn't end up using YARN as master:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
import os

from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

def read_cluster_file(file_path, spark, table_name):
    cluster_data = spark.read.csv(file_path, header=True, mode="DROPMALFORMED")    
    cluster_data.createOrReplaceTempView(table_name)

    return cluster_data

def main():
    spark = SparkSession.builder.master("yarn").appName("gene_cluster").getOrCreate()
    dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    cluster_data = read_cluster_file("file:"+dir+"/gene_cluster.csv", ",", spark, "cluster")
    result_df = spark.sql("SELECT `subunits(Entrez IDs)` FROM cluster")
    result_df.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

How do I make my Spark application run with YARN master programmatically in Python?

I have tried:

- `.setMaster("yarn-client")` and `.setMaster("yarn-cluster")`.
- Using SQLContext and the new SparkSession.

Comment: Is there any output of this script?

Comment: @znurgl no, other than printing stuff to console.

Comment: can you try with spark pi example then you can get to know problem with yarn or not.

`spark-submit  --master yarn --deploy-mode client    --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi  /usr/hdp/2.3.4.7-4/spark/lib/spark-examples-1.5.2.2.3.4.7-4-hadoop2.7.1.2.3.4.7-4.jar 10`

Comment: @Arvind Kumar Anugula He already mentioned that specifying master with spark-submit works but it does work when its being set from program itself.

Comment: Is Spark running locally? If that is on a remote machine, that cluster_thata could be the problem and not SparkSession. Could you print spark out?

Comment: @znurgl I am running Spark locally on my laptop. Printing spark gives: <pyspark.sql.session.SparkSession object at 0x7f50720b07f0>

Comment: Try using a full spark URL: SparkSession.builder.master("spark://yarn:7077").appName("gene_cluster").getOrCreate()

Comment: @znurgl doesn't work, it doesn't show up in YARN GUI, unlike specifying master from CLI.

Comment: @Dobob wondering if you found a solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue in HDP2.5  . I am using the SparkSession API and even though i set the master as 'yarn' , SparkContext is created in local mode and none of my yarn related configuration is effective. I also checked if there is any issue with cluster setup by submitting a sample application using spark-submit with below command.

`spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi /usr/hdp/2.5.0.0-1245/spark/lib/spark-examples-1.6.2.2.5.0.0-1245-hadoop2.7.3.2.5.0.0-1245.jar 10`

The job executed pretty well and from Spark WebUI i can clearly see it ran as a cluster job and executors are distributed among my worker nodes.

After digging a bit into spark code, it seems that using pyspark , the sc is created even with out taking the configuration into consideration and once created the configuration is applied .There are some specific configurations which can be effective even after the spark context is initialised but some has to be properly set at the time of initialisation. I finally managed to run the job by setting PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS.

`export PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS="--master yarn pyspark-shell"`

Look into java_gateway.py in the pyspark code for further understanding. We will be soon moving to HDP3.0 and will update if this is necessary in the latest version.